# ng-repeat when dealing with 2 loops

Tags: angularjs

I currently have the code: (copy and pasted from my plunkr)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">

<head>
<title>Services and Modules</title>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.2.22" data-semver="1.2.22" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.2.0" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link data-require="bootstrap-theme@3.2.0" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<script>
angular.module("exampleApp", [])
  .controller("defaultCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
      cities: ["London", "New York", "Paris"],
      countries: ["UK", "US", "France"]
    };
  });
</script>
</head>

  <body ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="val in data">
  <li ng-repeat="a in val">{{a}}</li>
  </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to print a unordered list of:

London, UK

New York, US

Paris, France

Without combining the cities and countries into one object and having an array of these objects. Would it be possible to do this with the format I currently have?

To clarify, I want something like this (but it isn't correct syntax)

```
<ul ng-repeat="cities in data.cities" ng-repeat="countries in data.countries">
<li>{{cities}}, {{countries}}</li>
```

Comment: Sorry, http://plnkr.co/edit/lQHdvAVMS9cq5YwNfPOY?p=streamer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are 100% sure both lists have the same length then you can use `$index` like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="city in data.cities">
  <li>{{city}}, {{data.countries[$index]}}</li>
</ul>
```

Though a better approach would be to just combine the lists. (I like the `_.zip` method myself too.)

http://plnkr.co/edit/qcYCmVe6mFlrrhuaMIJ1?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>[zip](http://underscorejs.org/#zip)</kbd> method from underscore.js:

```
$scope.data = {
  cities: ["London", "New York", "Paris"],
  countries: ["UK", "US", "France"]
};

$scope.newArray = _.zip($scope.data.cities,$scope.data.countries)
```

The result should be:

```
[
  [
    "London",
    "UK"
  ],
  [
    "New York",
    "US"
  ],
  [
    "Paris",
    "France"
  ]
]
```

*HTML*

```
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="row in newArray">{{row}}</li>
 </ul>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/G5qY2MtcmXzHi44zHLpt?p=preview)**</kbd>

---

*Reference*

> zip_.zip(*arrays) 
>   Merges together the values of each of the arrays with the values at the corresponding position. Useful when you have separate data sources that are coordinated through matching array indexes. If you're working with a matrix of nested arrays, _.zip.apply can transpose the matrix in a similar fashion.
>
> _.zip(['moe', 'larry', 'curly'], [30, 40, 50], [true, false, false]);
>   => [["moe", 30, true], ["larry", 40, false], ["curly", 50, false]]
>
> *.zip.apply(*, arrayOfRowsOfData);
>   => arrayOfColumnsOfData

Comment: I want them in one line. IE London, UK is 1 li.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't join both as an object, but the index position of each array are the pair you want, you can do something like

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="city in data.cities">{{city}}, {{data.countries[$index]}}</li>
</ul>
```

$index is an variable that is created by the ng-repeat, that you can use to know the iteration step where you are